# loading lines of text to variables

Tags: vb.net, file, variables, minecraft

There is this text file, a `.proporties` file and I want to open it in `VB.NET` with individual lines in individual variables, if that's possible.

It is a file from a minecraft server, like this:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Sun Nov 08 18:01:24 CET 2015
spawn-protection=16
max-tick-time=60000
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=0
broadcast-console-to-ops=true
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=1
spawn-monsters=true
op-permission-level=4
resource-pack-hash=
announce-player-achievements=true
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=20
network-compression-threshold=256
max-world-size=29999984
server-port=25565
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
generate-structures=true
online-mode=true
max-build-height=256
level-seed=
motd=A Minecraft Server
enable-rcon=false
```

Is there a way I can load the text with each line in a individual line:

```
dim line1 as string = readline1
dim line2 as string = readline2
dim line3 as string = readline3
```

So I could put it in this kind of form

[image: CLICK ON ME FOR THE IMAGE]

and when it's loaded, is there a way I can split the text, because I only need the value, for example: `max-tick-time=60000` I only need `60000`.

Is this possible to do and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: `is there a way i can load the text with each line in a individual line`  yes.  `is there a way i can split the text` also yes.  No go forth and Google

Comment: Of course this is possible but it seems as if you've put very little effort into attempting the problem yourself.  Try reading about *FileSystem Operations in VB.NET*.

Comment: We have software that can beat humans at Jeapordy by itself but you don't think it is possible to read from a text file?

Comment: i know its posible but i couldt find it. sorry, so i asked here and i got a awnser and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily read each line from a file using [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can split the keys from the values using the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

I would suggest putting all of the key/value pairs in a Dictionary instance and then assigning them to variables:

```
    'Variable that holds your list of settings.
    Dim lstSettings As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    'Loop through each line.
    For Each strLine As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Some\FilePath.txt")

        'Ignore empty lines and comments.
        If strLine.Length > 0 AndAlso strLine.Substring(0, 1) <> "#" Then

            'Split the Key from the Value.
            Dim lstKeyValue As List(Of String) = strLine.Split("=").ToList()

            'Some additional filtering of bad data.
            If lstKeyValue.Count = 2 Then

                'Add to the Dictionary instance.
                lstSettings.Add(lstKeyValue(0), lstKeyValue(1))

            End If

        End If

    Next

    'Now assign the values to your variables or UI.
    Dim bolForceGameMode As Boolean = CBool(lstSettings("force-gamemode"))
    Dim intViewDistance As Integer = CInt(lstSettings("view-distance"))
    'etc

    'Or directly manipulate the UI:
    'txtViewDistance.Text = lstSettings("view-distance")
```

Comment: oh thanks, it works,

Now is there also a way to save it again from the variables?

Comment: System.IO.File.WriteAllText(strYourStringVariable). You'd be better off serializing/deserializing  XML though.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it works for you!
If you don't know what some code do just tell me i'll explain

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim properties As String() = {}
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim text As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("") 'You put the file location here
        Dim alltext As String() = text.Split(Environment.NewLine)
        For i = 2 To alltext.Length - 1
            Array.Resize(properties, properties.Length + 1)
            properties(properties.Length - 1) = alltext(i).Split("=")(0)
            Array.Resize(properties, properties.Length + 1)
            properties(properties.Length - 1) = alltext(i).Split("=")(1)
        Next
    End Sub

    Function setting(val As String)
        For i = 0 To properties.Length - 1
            If properties(i).Contains(val) Then
                Return properties(i + 1)
            End If
        Next
        Return "No results found."
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(setting(TextBox1.Text)) 'You find the setting with this setting("max-tick-time")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You call the function like this:

```
Dim allowFlight As String = setting("allow-flight")
```

Comment: oh thanks, I already used the awnser above but thanks for the fast response, Now I got still 1 question: is there also a way to save it again from the variables?

Comment: I know the answer but it's connected to this code so i can't help you with the other one except the fact that you must use string builder and then FileSystem.WriteAllText
Info about the string builder: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172824.aspx)